# Is sqlalchemy filtering duplicates?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a `sqlalchamy` query and an `SQL` query which I think are identical but return different results.  Is there something I am missing about `sqlalchemy`?

sqlalchemy code:

```
session.query(Table1)\
       .join(Table2)\
       .join(Table3)\
       .filter(Table3.data == X)\
       .filter(Table1.other_data == Y)\
       .all()
```

SQL query:

```
select Table1.*
from Table1
join Table2 on Table2.table1_id = Table1.id
join Table3 on Table2.id = Table3.table2_id
where Table3.data = X
      and Table1.other_data = Y;
```

`Table2` has foreign key in `Table1` and `Table3` has foreign in table `Table2` so sqlalchemy should be able to join them nicely. `Table3` has no foreign key from `Table1`.

The `sqlalchemy` code returns 1 result while the `SQL` returns 3 duplicates so my question is: Is `sqlalchemy` doing something I don't know?

Comment: It does sort of filter duplicates, if querying for a single ORM entity only. Can't remember where's the relevant part in the docs, though. But think about it: the ORM handles objects by their identity, so were it to return 3 results, it would return 3 references to the same object.

Comment: @IljaEverilä That is true but I don't see why it should be a problem. If you wanted distinct in `sqlalchemy` you can use distinct(it exists) and if you get 3 references to  object and try to edit all of them you should get an error.

Comment: Nope, you'd just edit one, observe changes in all, as is the tradition with multiple references to a single mutable object.